# How to create a table with if statements for each row in each column in r

Tags: r

I would like to create a new output that is based on an if statement for each row in each column for example:

If the value of the year for each flower in table 1 is smaller than the min for each flower in each year in table 2 then the value will be the value of min in table 2, else the value of year in table 1

I have an idea of how the code could look but not sure how to type it to create the output I need so that it is applied to each flower for each year.

```
IF (Table1$year < Table2$min, Table2$min, Table1$year)
```

(table 1)

| flower | 1902 | 1950 | 2010 | 2012 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 23 | 23 | 23 | 31 | 36 |
| rose | 50 | 110 | 115 | 131 | 131 |
| daisy | 30 | 37 | 47 | 49 | 49 |

(table 2)

| flower | year | min |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lily | 1902 | 15 |
| rose | 1902 | 100 |
| daisy | 1902 | 35 |
| lily | 1950 | 23 |
| rose | 1950 | 50 |
| daisy | 1950 | 30 |
| lily | 2010 | 16 |
| rose | 2010 | 50 |
| daisy | 2010 | 67 |

The output for the first year will look like:

| flower | 1902 |
| --- | --- |
| lily | 23 |
| rose | 100 |
| daisy | 35 |

Comment: Reconsider wide format data frames with data elements like year stored in headers. Keep data long (or [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html)) like your table 2 which is better for cleaning, aggregating, merging, plotting, modeling, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will help to make the first table match the "long" form of the 2nd table. Then you could join the two tables together, pick the max value for each flower-year combination, and then reshape wide:

```
library(dplyr)
t1_long %>%
  left_join(t2) %>%
  group_by(flower, year) %>%
  summarize(max = max(value, min, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = max, names_prefix = "x"))
```

Result

```
Joining, by = c("flower", "year")
# A tibble: 3 × 6
  flower x1902 x1950 x2010 x2012 x2021
  <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 daisy     35    37    67    49    49
2 lily      23    23    23    31    36
3 rose     100   110   115   131   131
```

---

To make your first table long, I used:

```
t1_long <- t1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-flower, names_to = "year") %>%
  mutate(year = parse_number(year))
```

Starting from the data below. Note that R advises against column names that start with a number: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f:

> A "syntactic" name for a data frame column "starts with either a
> letter or a dot not followed by a number."

```
t1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  flower = c("lily", "rose", "daisy"),
  x1902 = c(23L, 50L, 30L),
  x1950 = c(23L, 110L, 37L),
  x2010 = c( 23L, 115L, 47L),
  x2012 = c( 31L, 131L, 49L),
  x2021 = c( 36L, 131L, 49L)
)


t2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              flower = c("lily","rose","daisy",
                         "lily","rose","daisy","lily","rose","daisy"),
                year = c(1902L,1902L,1902L,1950L,
                         1950L,1950L,2010L,2010L,2010L),
               min = c(15L, 100L, 35L, 23L, 50L, 30L, 16L, 50L, 67L)
  )
```